# How to install OpenJDK library?

Tags: java, python, anaconda, h2o, azure-machine-learning-service

I created the following `environment.yml` file from my local Anaconda that contains an openjdk package.

```
name: venv
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - openjdk=11.0.6
```

[image: Anaconda openjdk]

However, Azure Machine Learning couldn't install the openjdk package from the `environment.yml` file as module is not found.

[image: ResolvePackageNotFound]

Backstory:

I'm building a machine learning model using H2O.ai Python library. Unfortunately, H2O.ai is written in Java so it requires Java to run. I've installed openjdk to my local Anaconda venv for running H2O.ai locally - it runs perfectly. However, I couldn't deploy this model to Azure Machine Learning because it couldn't install openjdk from requirements.txt or environment.yml as module not found.

Comment: Looks like I was answering as you were editing! It is better to post a self-answer, rather than put it in your question (but maybe that is something you need 100 rep for?).

Comment: If you managed to solve your problem, then please post an **answer** with the solution. Do not add things like "(solved)" to the title, nor add the solution to your **question**. I have rolled back your last edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

Install openjdk through conda but specify conda-forge as the channel to install the package from.

```
name: venv
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - conda-forge::openjdk=11.0.9.1
```

[image: Conda Forge]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have terminal access? `sudo apt install default-jdk` should work on Debian-based systems (such as Ubuntu); or if you need a specific version, e.g. JDK 14: `sudo apt install openjdk-14-jdk`

Alternatively, there is a guide to [installing H2O on Azure](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cloud-integration/azure-dsvm.html) in the manual; apparently H2O is available in the Marketplace.